# RelativeLayout inside Scrollview expands more than screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have this layout, scrollview with relative layout, I added scrollview because on smaller devices RelativeLayout alone will cut off parts of the layout that goes over the screen size, so anything bigger than screen height is not visible.

I tried adding to RelativeLayout wrap_content to height,but that did not fix it, so I added scrollview, now the whole layout is shown, but on devices that have bigger screens like nexus 4, the Relative Layout stretches over the screen height, so the user has to scroll to see the bottom textViews.

Anyway I know the problem is with this ImageView that has drawable:src=@drawable/background

This forces the relative layout to take more than screen height, I use centerCrop for the image, the height of the image is 1200, and the height of the nexus 4 is 1280, so the ImageView is supposed to fit the screen but it stretches the whole Layout. The black line is aproximalty where the screen ends and instead of cutting the imageView at that point the RelativeLayout exapnds after that point...

[image: sample layout image]

How can I ensure that my RelativeLayout does not go over the screen height on devices with bigger resolution, but on smaller ones to include scrolling for content that can not fit the screen height? Currently I have to scroll to she the bottom textViews on all devices..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="-20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophystack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/trophystack" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTrophyStackLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_address"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon2"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="user@email.com"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:minWidth="250dp"
                android:tag="login_email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="********"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:tag="login_password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/doLogin"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttontexture1"
                android:minWidth="200dp"
                android:onClick="goQueue"
                android:text="Sign In"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Forgot password?"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sign_up_text2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="New here?"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sign_up_text"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/llTrophyStackLogin"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:onClick="doSwipe"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/forgot_password_text"
            android:layout_below="@id/llTrophyStackLogin"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:onClick="doForgotPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your layout's screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
android:src="@drawable/background"
```

from `ImageView` and set this as a background for `RelativeLayout`.

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: I tried that but the image aspect ratio will be askew, because in that case scaleType is fitXY

Comment: you need to remove that ImageView if not neccessary.

Comment: you can also add your ScrollView in linear layout and then set backgriund for it.

Comment: yeah I guess that is the way to go, I will wait a bit more then accept your answer if no others answers are posted..